# Break up a string with HTML embedded in for translations purpose

Tags: c#, .net, string-interpolation

I am on a .NET Framework project and on my C# code I am getting a value which is as follow:

`object.value = "In total <B>85</B> courses.<br/><ul><li><B>13</B> have been started</li><li><B>42</B> have not been started</li><li><B>30</B> have been completed"`

I am supposed to translate the text based on the language, in the above case:

- In total
- courses
- have been started
- have not been started
- have been completed

and maintain numbers and HTML.
As a outcomes I would like exactly the same layout but with the text translated.

I was gonna try something like this:

`var headers = $"{0} <B>{1}</B> {2}.<br/><ul><li><B>{3}</B> {4}</li><li><B>{5}</B> {6}</li><li><B>{7}</B> {8}";`

but then I am not sure how to create the arrays correctly.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: *"how to create the arrays correctly"* - what arrays?

Comment: Well, I mean Array or whatever is best to accomplish what I am after

Comment: Well, you could just use variables? `var headers = $"{totalText} <B>{courses}</B> {coursesText}.<br/><ul><li><B>{started}</B> {startedText}</li><li><B>{notStarted}</B> {notStartedText}</li><li><B>{completed}</B> {completedText}";`

Comment: The numbers can change, the text shouldn't but I would like to get it to work also with the possibility where the text changes.

How do I extrapolate for instance totalText, courses, coursesText, etc... from that String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var str = "In total <B>85</B> courses.<br/><ul><li><B>13</B> have been started</li>" +
    "<li><B>42</B> have not been started</li><li><B>30</B> have been completed";

var parts = Regex.Split(str, @"<[A-Za-z\/]+>").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

foreach(var p in parts)
    str = str.Replace(p, MyTranslateMethod(p));
```

Comment: That looks great :) - Thanks a lot!